# Do public folders have a 'Drafts' folder?

Tags: exchange-2013

Exchange 2013 - Migrated Public folder to a Shared Folder and in the process deleted the user account for the public folder. Now end user says they are missing Drafts from old public folder? PST exported and imported to move emails from public folder to Shared mailbox. Does that not grab drafts?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no "Drafts" folder in a public folder, and per my knowledge, PST export action will not apply to drafts items.